# Complex MySQL query summing joined records where parent and child ids are equal

Tags: mysql, join

Maybe this will be an easy one for some of you MySQL masters who see this stuff like a level 3 children's book.

I have multiple tables that I'm joining to produce statistical data for a report and I'm getting tripped up at the moment trying to figure it out. It's obviously imperative the figures are correct because it impacts a number of decisions going forward.

Here's the lay of the land (not the full picture, but you'll get the point):

Affiliate Table

```
+----+-----------+------------+---------------------+
| id | firstname | lastname   | created_date        |
+----+-----------+------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Mike      | Johnson    | 2010-11-22 17:44:37 |
|  2 | Trevor    | Wilson     | 2010-12-23 16:24:24 |
|  3 | Bob       | Parker     | 2011-11-04 10:33:49 |
+----+-----------+------------+---------------------+
```

Now our query should only find results for Bob Parker (id 3) so I'll only show example results for Bob.

Affiliate Link Table

```
+-----+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| id  | parent_id | affiliate_id | link_type | linkhash | created_date        |
+-----+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
|  21 |      NULL |            3 | PRODUCT   | fa2e82a7 | 2011-06-15 16:18:37 |
|  27 |      NULL |            3 | PRODUCT   | 55de2ae7 | 2011-06-23 01:03:00 |
|  28 |      NULL |            3 | PRODUCT   | 02cae72f | 2011-06-23 01:03:00 |
|  29 |        27 |            3 | PRODUCT   | a4dfb2c8 | 2011-06-23 01:03:00 |
|  30 |        28 |            3 | PRODUCT   | 72cea1b2 | 2011-06-23 01:03:00 |
|  36 |        21 |            3 | PRODUCT   | fa2e82a7 | 2011-06-23 01:07:03 |
|  59 |        21 |            3 | PRODUCT   | ec33413f | 2011-11-04 17:49:17 |
|  60 |        27 |            3 | PRODUCT   | f701188c | 2011-11-04 17:49:17 |
|  69 |        21 |            3 | PRODUCT   | 6dfb89fd | 2011-11-04 17:49:17 |
+-----+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
```

Affiliate Stats

```
+--------+--------------+--------------------+----------+---------------------+
| id     | affiliate_id | link_id | order_id | type     | created_date        |
+--------+--------------+---------+----------+----------+---------------------+
|  86570 |            3 |      21 |     NULL | CLICK    | 2013-01-01 00:07:31 |
|  86574 |            3 |      21 |     NULL | PAGEVIEW | 2013-01-01 00:08:53 |
|  86579 |            3 |      21 |      411 | SALE     | 2013-01-01 00:09:52 |
|  86580 |            3 |      36 |     NULL | CLICK    | 2013-01-01 00:09:55 |
|  86582 |            3 |      36 |     NULL | PAGEVIEW | 2013-01-01 00:09:56 |
|  86583 |            3 |      28 |     NULL | CLICK    | 2013-01-01 00:11:04 |
|  86584 |            3 |      28 |     NULL | PAGEVIEW | 2013-01-01 00:11:04 |
|  86586 |            3 |      30 |     NULL | CLICK    | 2013-01-01 00:30:18 |
|  86587 |            3 |      30 |     NULL | PAGEVIEW | 2013-01-01 00:30:20 |
|  86611 |            3 |      69 |     NULL | CLICK    | 2013-01-01 00:40:19 |
|  86613 |            3 |      69 |     NULL | PAGEVIEW | 2013-01-01 00:40:19 |
|  86619 |            3 |      69 |      413 | SALE     | 2013-01-01 00:42:12 |
|  86622 |            3 |      60 |     NULL | CLICK    | 2013-01-01 00:46:00 |
|  86624 |            3 |      60 |     NULL | PAGEVIEW | 2013-01-01 00:46:01 |
|  86641 |            3 |      60 |     NULL | PAGEVIEW | 2013-01-01 00:55:58 |
|  86642 |            3 |      30 |      415 | SALE     | 2013-01-01 00:56:35 |
|  86643 |            3 |      28 |     NULL | PAGEVIEW | 2013-01-01 00:56:43 |
|  86644 |            3 |      60 |      417 | SALE     | 2013-01-01 00:56:52 |
+--------+--------------+---------+----------+----------+---------------------+
```

Orders

```
+------+--------------+---------+---------------------+
| id   | affiliate_id | total   | created_date        |
+------+--------------+---------+---------------------+
|  411 |            3 |  138.62 | 2013-01-01 00:09:50 |
|  413 |            3 |  312.87 | 2013-01-01 00:09:52 |
|  415 |            3 |  242.59 | 2013-01-01 00:09:55 |
|  417 |            3 |  171.18 | 2013-01-01 00:09:55 |
+------+--------------+---------+---------------------+
```

Now the results that I need should look like this (only show main/parent link id)

```
+---------+---------+
| link_id | total   |
+---------+---------+
|      21 |  451.49 | <- 1 order from parent (21), 1 from child (69)
|      27 |  171.18 | <- 1 order from child (69)
|      28 |  242.59 | <- 1 order from child (30)
+---------+---------+
```

I'm not quite sure how to write the query so that I can sum where affiliate_link.id and affiliate_link.parent_id are combined. Is this even possible with a couple of JOINs and GROUPing?

Comment: How many "levels" might there be to AffiliateLinks?  That is, might a link that has a non-`NULL` parent_id also be the parent of another link?

Comment: That's not going to be possible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Looking at the data supplied I don't see how 21 and 69 are linked.

Comment: Link ID 69 has a parent_id of 21.

Comment: Where do the `create_date` values in the resultset come from?

Comment: You're right, that was not suppose to be in the resultset, I've updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure why you have denormalised `affiliate_id` (by placing it in each table) and, therefore, whether one can rely on all Stats and Orders that stem from a particular Link to have the same `affiliate_id` as that Link.

If it's possible, I'd suggest changing the `AffiliateLink.parent_id` column such that parent records point to themselves (rather than `NULL`):

```
UPDATE AffiliateLink SET parent_id = id WHERE parent_id IS NULL
```

Then it's a simple case of joining and grouping:

```
SELECT   AffiliateLink.parent_id AS link_id,
         SUM(Orders.total) AS total
FROM     AffiliateLink
    JOIN AffiliateStats ON AffiliateStats.link_id = AffiliateLink.id
    JOIN Orders         ON Orders.id = AffiliateStats.order_id
WHERE    AffiliateLink.affiliate_id = 3
GROUP BY AffiliateLink.parent_id
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c57a8/1/0).

If it's not possible to make the change, you can effectively create the resulting `AffiliateLink` table using `UNION` (but beware the performance implications, as MySQL will not be able to use indexes on the result):

```
(
  SELECT parent_id, id, affiliate_id FROM AffiliateLink WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
  SELECT id       , id, affiliate_id FROM AffiliateLink WHERE parent_id IS NULL
) AS AffiliateLink
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d44c/1/0).

Comment: Ahh, didn't think about the parent_id being NULL as a problem. I can certainly see that now though. Also, I don't quite get the denormalized comment. If the Affiliate Link did not have the affiliate_id then how would I know who's link it is. And if it's not part of the stats then I would certainly have to look up the link to get the affiliate just to associate the stat to an affiliate.

Comment: @Tomas: Yes, it certainly needs to be in the `AffiliateLink` table, but its duplication in `AffiliateStats` and `Orders` is a violation of [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).  That's not the end of the world: denormalisation can often be deliberately introduced for performance reasons; but unless there's some particular problem with "*looking up the link to get the affiliate*" (after all it's just a join on, hopefully indexed, columns), I'd be tempted to stick with 3NF.

Comment: I guess some times it is just a case of laziness as it is here really. Thanks.